# Multivariate Granger Test on Single Variables

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, vector-autoregression, granger-causality, wald-test

Say I have some trivariate model with variables X, Y, Z. Now I want to know if X granger causes Y.
To do this test I have used the `causality()` function in `library(vars)`. This however does not test if X granger causes Y, but it can check if X granger causes Y and Z or if X and Z granger cause Y. So the output method is:

```
Granger causality H0: X Z do not Granger-cause Y
```

or

```
Granger causality H0: X do not Granger-cause Y Z
```

A problem is probably that this method does it this way to calculate a simpler test statistic. Now I also checked out the `grangertest` function in `library(imtest)`. This method does sadly only work for bivariate or univariate models.

Do you know what function to use to test if X causes Y?

Answer (score 0):

there is a package in CRAN available BruceR;

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bruceR/index.html

You can use the `granger_causality()` function, which is based in VAR objects created with `vars` package.

As is described

> Granger test of predictive causality (between multivariate time series) based on vector autoregression (VAR) model. Its output resembles the output of the vargranger command in Stata (but here
> using an F test).

Remember this test should be used if you have only stationary time series in your VAR model